# How to adjust query so it can return multiple rows to fix 'single-row subquery returns more than one row' error

Tags: sql

I want to find all the stocks in the database that have `Bank` in their name. It will normally return multiple rows and display the name and price.

```
<price> Bank of America 
<price> Bank of NewYork
<price> Bank United
```

However I am getting a `single-row subquery returns more than one row` error.

Which I gather is because the sub query returns more than one row. So I want the main query to display multiple columns and rows.

```
SELECT PRICE, STOCKNAME                  
    from ALL_PRICES
    WHERE STOCKNAME = (SELECT STOCKNAME
        FROM ALL_STOCKS
        WHERE STOCKNAME LIKE '%Bank%')
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: replace ` =` with `IN`

Comment: get rid of the subquery, you already have stockname in table all_prices.  SELECT price, stockname  FROM all_prices WHERE stockname LIKE '%Bank%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT PRICE, STOCKNAME                  
    from ALL_PRICES
    WHERE STOCKNAME in (SELECT STOCKNAME
        FROM ALL_STOCKS
        WHERE STOCKNAME LIKE '%Bank%')
```

EDIT:

A better answer (courtesy of Christian Palmer):

```
SELECT PRICE, 
       STOCKNAME                  
from ALL_PRICES
WHERE STOCKNAME LIKE '%Bank%'
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks JohnHC and JaydipJ.

Comment: @John, Christian Palmer's comment above has an even better query.